# How to cleanup INVENTDIM table?

Tags: axapta

In AX2009, there exists a process to cleanup unused inventory dimensions not belonging to any transaction.

Is there such a process that I can do in AX4 where INVENTDIM table is now having 20 million+ records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's no such a standard process you can try the following.

1. write a job to identify all `InventDimId` (+`ReqCovInventDimId`,
   etc.) fields in all the tables.
2. write a job or a SQL query to fill in a
   temporary table with the `InventDimId` values from all these fields.
3. write a job or a SQL query to remove all such records from the `InventDim` table that don't have `InventDimId`'s in this temporary table.

Comment: This is what the functionality in AX2009 does actually. Looks like it is compatible with AX4.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such standard process.

The courageous might do:

```
InventDim.skipDeleteActions(true);
InventDim.skipDeleteMethod(true);
delete_from InventDim
    notexists join InventTrans
        where InventTrans.inventDimId == InventDim.inventDimId;
```

This will delete any records not referenced by item transactions.
Unfortunately there might exists other references.

You could try a downgrade of the AX 2009 process.